# Python dictionary Index Error: List Index out of range

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a newbie to learning python, and am working on my first project. I've made some progress, and last night had some code that was working, including a dictionary. But now, whenever I try to run the code, the dictionary throws a list index error. My searching has suggested that this would be (I think) because one of the list indexes used in the dictionary is out of the range of the list that's defined, but as far as I can see, that is not the case. I've scoured for suitable answers, and my code to see if I can find what's wrong, and I've had no joy.

The code is:

```
board = [[' ','|',' ','|',' '],['-',' ','-',' ','-'],[' ','|',' ','|',' '],['-',' ','-',' ','-'],[' ','|',' ','|',' ']]

coords = {'1':board[0][0],'2':[0][2],'3':board[0][4],'4':board[2][0],'5':board[2][2],'6':board[2][4],'7':board[4][0],'8':board[4][2],'9':board[4][4]}
```

I'm really struggling to see what's causing the error, so any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: `'2':[0][2]` should be `'2':boards[0][2]` I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a board after '2': in your dict,

this will work :

```
board = [[' ','|',' ','|',' '],['-',' ','-',' ','-'],[' ','|',' ','|',' '],['-',' ','-',' ','-'],[' ','|',' ','|',' ']]

coords = {'1':board[0][0],'2':board[0][2],'3':board[0][4],'4':board[2][0],'5':board[2][2],'6':board[2][4],'7':board[4][0],'8':board[4][2],'9':board[4][4]}
```